# Error while passing values using peekpoketester

Tags: chisel

I am trying to pass some random integers (which I have stored in an array) to my hardware as an Input through the poke method in peekpoketester. But I am getting this error:

chisel3.internal.ChiselException: Error: Not in a UserModule. Likely cause: Missed Module() wrap, bare chisel API call, or attempting to construct hardware inside a BlackBox.

What could be the reason? I don't think I need a module wrap here as this is not hardware.

```
class TesterSimple (dut: DeviceUnderTest)(parameter1 : Int)(parameter2 : Int) extends
PeekPokeTester (dut) {
 var x = Array[Int](parameter1) 
 var y = Array[Int](parameter2) 
 var z = 1 
 poke(dut.io.IP1, z.asUInt)
 for(i <- 0 until parameter1){poke(dut.io.IP2(i), x(i).asUInt)}
 for(j <- 0 until parameter2){poke(dut.io.IP3(j), y(j).asUInt)}
}

object TesterSimple extends App {
 implicit val parameter1 = 2
 implicit val parameter2 = 2
 chisel3.iotesters.Driver (() => DeviceUnderTest(parameter1 :Int, parameter2 :Int)) { c =>
 new TesterSimple (c)(parameter1, parameter2)}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest a couple of things.

1. Main problem, I think you are not initializing your arrays properly

   1. Try using `Array.fill` or `Array.tabulate` to create and initialize arrays

```
  val rand = scala.util.Random
  var x = Array.fill(parameter1)(rand.nextInt(100))
  var y = Array.fill(parameter2)(rand.nextInt(100))
```

1. You don't need the `.asUInt` in the `poke`, it accepts `Int`s or `BigInt`s
2. When defining hardware constants, use `.U` instead of `.asUInt`, the latter is a way of casting other chisel types, it does work but it a backward compatibility thing.
3. It's better to not start variables or methods with capital letters
4. I suggest us `class DutName(val parameter1: Int, val parameter2: Int)` or `class DutName(val parameter1: Int)(val parameter2: Int)` if you prefer.

   1. This will allow to use the dut's paremeters when you are writing your test.
   2. E.g. `for(i <- 0 until dut.parameter1){poke(dut.io.IP2(i), x(i))}`
   3. This will save you have to duplicate parameter objects on your DUT and your Tester

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the 4th point was really helpful, I did not know about that.

Answer (score 0):

Could you also share your DUT?
I believe the most likely case is your DUT does not extend `Module`

Comment: No my DUT does extend Module, I edited my post and added the object as well.